# Set default middleware in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

I am new in Laravel Framework. I want to set a middleware that will be called in all HTTP requests. How I set that middleware?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/middleware#global-middleware

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use global middleware. From [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/middleware#global-middleware):

> If you want a middleware to run during every HTTP request to your application, list the middleware class in the `$middleware` property of your `app/Http/Kernel.php` class.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a middleware to run during every HTTP request to your application, list **the middleware class in the $middleware property of your app/Http/Kernel.php class it's called global middleware**.

Let's take example

Creating Middleware

We can easily create new middleware using artisan.

```
php artisan make:middleware AdMiddleware
```

After we’ve created a new middleware component, we then need to look at modifying the code to suit our needs.

Updating our Middleware File:

After you’ve ran the make:middleware command you should see your new middleware file in app/http/middleware. Open this up and we’ll create a middleware that will get the request’s IP address and then determine what country that request came from.

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class AdMiddleware {

    /** * Handle an incoming request. 
     * * * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request 
     * * @param \Closure $next * @return mixed */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next) { // Test to see if the requesters have an ip address. 
        if ($request->ip() == null) {
            throw new \Exception("IP ADDRESS NOT SET");
        } $country = file_get_contents('http://api.hostip.info/get_html.php?ip=' . $request->ip());
        echo $country;
        if (strpos($country, "UNITED STATES")) {
            throw new \Exception("NOT FOR YOUR EYES, NSA");
        } else {
            return redirect("index");
        } return $next($request);
    }

}
```

This code basically takes in a request and as an example checks to see it’s location before deciding whether to display a US only ad or an advertisement suited for the rest of the world. This could be quite beneficial for those of you who want to build up a site that features amazon affiliate links from multiple countries.

Note that you shouldn't be passing anything back in the middleware section, you should instead be passing redirects to views instead of printing out things like I've done for brevity.

Registering your Middleware

When registering your middleware you have 2 choices. First choice is that you add the middleware to be run on every request handled by your app. You can do that by opening up App\Http\Kernel.php and adding it to your $middleware array like so:

```
protected $middleware = [
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
    \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
    \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
    // our new class. 
    \App\http\Middleware\AdMiddleware::class,
];
```

Second choice is to have the middleware run on registered routes only, you can register it like so:

```
 <?php

    /** * The application's route middleware.
     *  * * @var array */
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'ad' => \App\Http\Middleware\AdMiddleware::class,
    ];
```

And then add the middleware to the specific routes like so:

```
Route::get('/ip', ['middleware' => 'ad', function() { return "IP"; }]);
```